# Skobbler : Set the language of advice instruction and the distance between the instructions

Tags: skmaps

I'am doing turn by turn navigation app, i have two questions to ask:

1- How can i change the language of advice instructions? i did like this :

```
SKAdvisorSettings *adviceSettings = [[SKAdvisorSettings alloc]init];
adviceSettings.advisorType = SKAdvisorTypeTextToSpeech;
adviceSettings.language  = SKAdvisorLanguageFR;
```

But i get always instruction in English.

2- How can i change the distance between advices, for example i want to speech instruction every 500/200/10 .

Thanks you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You have to do the following settings when the route is calculated:

```
SKAdvisorSettings *settings = [SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings];
         settings.advisorVoice =  @"fr";
         settings.language  = SKAdvisorLanguageFR;
         [SKRoutingService sharedInstance].advisorConfigurationSettings = settings;
```

2. For configuring the distance to audio advice you will have to modify the advice_places.adv file
   On iOS: inside the SKAdvisorResources.bundle the /Configs/ folder

In there, for each type of instruction (crossing = turn left or right, highway exit, roundabout, etc.) there are 3 advices generated at 3 different distances (we actually have 2 sets of distances, one when outside of cities and one when inside a city). Modify those distances to achieve the "only 10-200+- meters before" requirement.