# Scout Android SDK: Support multi language only work in English

Tags: android, maps, voice, skmaps

I am using Android Skobbler SDK. I want that the routing advices work in multilanguages. I put inside SKMaps/Advisor/Languages all languages with advisor_configfiles and sound_files folders. Then in my code I have:

```
final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = initMapSettings.getAdvisorSettings();
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(mapResourcesPath +"/Advisor");
    advisorSettings.setResourcePath(mapResourcesPath +"/Advisor/Languages");
    advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_ES);
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("es");
    initMapSettings.setAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
```

With this code I should hear the intructions in spanish, but it does not work. If I change and put this code:

```
final SKAdvisorSettings advisorSettings = initMapSettings.getAdvisorSettings();
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorConfigPath(mapResourcesPath +"/Advisor");
    advisorSettings.setResourcePath(mapResourcesPath +"/Advisor/Languages");
    advisorSettings.setLanguage(SKAdvisorSettings.SKAdvisorLanguage.LANGUAGE_EN);
    advisorSettings.setAdvisorVoice("en");
    initMapSettings.setAdvisorSettings(advisorSettings);
```

I can hear the instructions in english

Can somebody help me?

Regards

Comment: For audio advice make sure you’ve downloaded the audio advice from here http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7250-Language-files-for-2-5-0-and-2-5-1 and add them in the folder

Comment: Thanks SylviA. Yes I used audio advices from https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k16z4npyl47218f/AAB-KL0qwfOVhFTeN11V4HNva?dl=0.

Comment: When I change my SKMaps.zip with all languages folder. My app crash with this message: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1)

Answer (score 1):

In the [SKAdvisorSettings class](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/navigation/SKAdvisorSettings.html) you have the SKAdvisorType enum which allows you to choose which one of them you would like to use. For changing the audio advisor settings used by the navigation component of the SDK, call setAudioAdvisorSettings method from the SKRouteManager class.See the documentation: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec017

Comment: Thanks SylviA. I have done and I copy the languages that I need (es, it, fr, de, en), but when I run the app crash. If I use the languages folder that I used before  and the app crash. Could you give me your SKMaps.zip?

Comment: the crash, I think is related to the way you're compressing the SKMaps.zip. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935460/what-process-should-be-used-to-compress-skmaps-zip-file-for-use-in-skobbler-powe