# Skobbler Android SDK: problems with SKMaps.zip

Tags: android, skmaps

I need to change the color routes. Then I unzip the SKMaps.zip file and modify an a line in daystyle/daystyle.json with the new hexadecimal color. Then I compress the SKMaps folder again to obtain SKMaps.zip and put it in assets folder.

When I run my projec obtain this error:

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 7411 (Thread-505)

I get the same error when I try to add new languages.

Can you help me?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix for this error: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7446-Fixing-quot-No-such-method-getlatitude-quot

Comment: Thanks Sylvia, I am using the new sdk but I am getting the same error. What is the problem? Regards

Comment: Check if the issue is related to how you re-archive the zip file once you've finished making changes. See the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935460/what-process-should-be-used-to-compress-skmaps-zip-file-for-use-in-skobbler-powe

Comment: Thanks Sylvia. This was the solution