# Skobbler - SKMaps - iOS - Advices languages incorrects

Tags: ios, swift, crash, skmaps

I've been researching in any forums about this problem that I'm facing, I believe be getting close to a fix and so, decided to ask in here for help and also to help any other one who needs this topic.

The problem involves that language in SKRouteAdvices. When retrieved through

```
SKRoutingService.sharedInstance().routeAdviceListWithDistanceFormat(.Metric)
```

an array of SKRouteAdvices was retrieved, but all of the advices were written in english, the voice was in portuguese but the .adviceInstruction was in english. I tried to set the advisorSettings (as I should anyway), it didn't work, but, for some unknown reason, when I set to TTS instead of pre-recorded audios, the advices were written portuguese but an weird voice (TSS) was in it instead the pre-recorded, as expected, actually. Then, tired of trying to find an obvious fix, decided to first do this, retrieve the portuguese advices, save in an array and then do it again but as did before to get the pre-recorded voice.

Turns out, the framework has some hidden problem with it, I tried a couple of different ways to get to it but the best I got was the result I wanted but with a 50% chance of crash, I really don't know why but sometimes it just did crash. So then I tried to do the TTS again but trying to getting the pre-recorded voices with the adviceInstruction property. It comes in portuguese and all the audios files are named in english so yes, and it doesn't work either.

Resuming everything: I need the SKRouteAdvices from my advices come in portuguese instruction and also in a pre-recorded voice. Any clue?

Comment: For audio advice you need to make sure you’ve downloaded the audio advice and add them in the folder. The next step that needs your attention is on how you re-archive the SKMaps.zip. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935460/what-process-should-be-used-to-compress-skmaps-zip-file-for-use-in-skobbler-powe

Comment: SylbiA, so, the audio are working (at least I think so), the thing is that I have no choice but choose between english instruction + correct portuguse audio or porgutuese instruction + no portuguese audio

Answer (score 2):

I give up trying to find a native way to get it, I followed Sylvia's suggest but I already did that before, I manage to get the result the I wanted by calling start navigation twice. In the first attempt I specify the advisorType (in SKAdvisorConfiguration in SKRoutingService.sharedInstance()) to .TextToSpeech, then, I grab the portuguese instructions and save in to a array and proceed to the second step, I repeat the configuration route and navigation with advisorType set to .AudioFiles.

With this strange combination I got what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The text instructions are generated based on the config files (for full details see http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/ and http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-faq/)

The bottom line is that due to how the audio files (.mp3) are linked together the text advices generated when using the "audio" option will not be "human readable".

For TTS support the advices meant to be read by a voice, hence they are "human readable".

Right now you cannot have both "mp3" advices and human understandable text instructions at the same time.